# The derivative of $\int_0^xxf(t)dt$ and why we cannot treat $xf$ as continuous.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

This comes from Calculus by Michael Spivak, 3rd ed., chapter 14, Problem 11.

> 11. Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x) = \int_0^x xf(t)dt$. The answer is *not* $xf(x)$; you should perform an obvious manipulation on the integral before trying to find $F'$.)

Here, Spivak fails to include the assumption that $f$ is continuous.

With this assumption, the answer is $\int_0^xf(t)dt + xf(x)$, and is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787756/754927), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1787756/754927), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/650033/754927).

I understand the solution. I was able to do it myself. It makes sense to me. I also solved it using the $\lim_{h\to 0}$ approach, and that worked too.

Yet, naively, it *seems* like the answer should be $xf(x)$. It *seems* like since $x$ "behaves like a constant" in that integration, and because $f$ is continuous, then $xf$ must also be continuous, and so $F'(c) = cf(c)$.

I'm hoping to build better intuition about why this is wrong.

I was thinking perhaps one way of looking at it is that $xf$ cannot be assumed to be continuous because we are free to change the value of $x$ somewhat arbitrarily. In fact, at any fixed point $c$, $xf(c)$ varies with $x$, so certainly we cannot guarantee anything about the value of $xf(t)$ simply by restricting $t$ to certain values.

Does this make any sense? I'm sorry to use such sloppy reasoning/language/arguments.

There's a good chance I just don't yet have the tools to fully "get it" yet, but I appreciate any insight you might be able to share.

**Edit**

Ian's answer helps explain something that confused me in Spivak's solution to a later problem.

The next two problems are:

> 12. Prove that if $f$ is continuous, then
>     $$\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)du = \int_0^x\left(\int_0^uf(t)dt\right)du.$$
>     Hint: Differentiate both sides, making use of Problem 11.

> 13. Use Problem 12 to prove that
>     $$\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)^2du = 2\int_0^x\left(\int_0^{u_2}\left(\int_0^{u_1}f(t)dt\right)du_1\right)du_2.$$

These each require fairly straightforward calculations, the details of which we can skip here. However, in the published Answer Book solution for the latter, problem 13, Spivak does something that initially I found baffling. He begins:

> Applying Problem 12 to $g(u) = f(u)(x-u)$, we obtain
> $$\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)^2du =\int_0^x[f(u)(x-u)](x-u)du$$
> $$=\int_0^x\left(\int_0^uf(t)(x-t)dt\right)du$$

This substitution is misleading. The result he's using from problem 12. applies only to functions that do *not* depend on $x$, while Spivak's $g$ here clearly *does* depend on $x$.

I think he gets away with it here only because $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(u)(x-u)] = f(u).$

Comment: It is just the product rule, nothing more.

Comment: There is a product rule that happens when you pull the $x$ out. If you could not do that because the integrand depended on $x$ in some more complicated way, the point would still be that the function depends on $x$ both through the limit of integration and the integrand. $xf(x)$ only captures the former contribution.

Comment: Ian, that is very helpful. The derivative of $\int_0^x7f(t)dt$ at $x = 7$ is $7f(7)$. This is not the same as the derivative of $\int_0^xxf(t)dt$ at $7$. The former doesn't have the same dependence on $x$, duh! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $F'(x)$ if $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^x xf(t)dt$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787750/find-fx-if-fx-displaystyle-int-0x-xftdt)

Comment: Thanks all for helping shed more light on this. @Ian, if you wish to paste your comment as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can solve the problem as

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x x f(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} \left ( x \int_0^x f(t) dt \right ) = \int_0^x f(t) dt + x f(x)$$

by the product rule together with FTC.

More generally you have the Leibniz rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t,x) dt \right ) = f(b(x),x) b'(x) - f(a(x),x) a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x) dt.$$

The Leibniz rule captures the dependence of the integral on $x$ through both the limits of integration and the integrand. In your problem, giving the answer $x f(x)$ would only encapsulate the dependence on the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus  says that the derivative of $\int_a^{x}  g(t)dt$ is $g(x)$ if $g$ is  continuous. This does not apply to the derivative of $\int_a^{x}  g(t,x)dt$. You cannot apply the theorem when the integrand depends on $x$ even if it continuous in both variables.

Comment: Understanding a theorem requires much needed focus on the hypotheses so that one does not jump to conclusion blindly. That the integrand must be independent of $x$ is very important here. +1